# change redirect location onClick.

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url, web

I'm trying to change a redirect link using check boxes that append to the URL and a button that uses the changed URL. Im still a beginner to JavaScript and am a little lost as to where i'm going wrong.

My code:

```
<html>

<form>

<div class="element1">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="id1" value="val1" class="hidden" ></label></div> 

<div class="element2">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="id2" value="val2" class="hidden" ></label></div> 

<div class="element3">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" id="id3" value="val3" class="hidden" ></div>


<div class="element00"> 
<input type="button"onclick="myFunction(calculatedUrl());" name="button1" id="itemA" value="valA" ></label></div> 

</form>

<script>
function calculatedUrl(){
  var totalString=""
  var link1="some text"
  var link2="more  text"
  var link3="something else"

   if(document.getElementById("id1").checked == true){
     var totalString = totalString.concat(link1);

}

 if(document.getElementById("id2").checked == true){
         var totalString = totalString.concat(link2);


}

 if(document.getElementById("id3").checked == true){
         var totalString = totalString.concat(link3);

}
  return totalString

}

function myFunction(id){
 var original="http://myoriginalurl"
 var addition=id
 var new=original.concat(addition)




//for testing
  window.alert(new)

  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML= new;


//for the real redirecting not active for now
//window.location=new
                          }




</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<form>

<div class="element1">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="id1" value="val1" class="hidden" ></label></div> 

<div class="element2">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="id2" value="val2" class="hidden" ></label></div> 

<div class="element3">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" id="id3" value="val3" class="hidden" ></div>


<div class="element00"> 
<input type="button"onclick="myFunction(calculatedUrl());" name="button1" id="itemA" value="valA" ></label></div> 

</form>

<script>
function calculatedUrl(){
  var totalString=""
  var link1="some text"
  var link2="more  text"
  var link3="something else"

   if(document.getElementById("id1").checked == true){
     var totalString = totalString.concat(link1);

}

 if(document.getElementById("id2").checked == true){
         var totalString = totalString.concat(link2);


}

 if(document.getElementById("id3").checked == true){
         var totalString = totalString.concat(link3);

}
  return totalString

}

function myFunction(id){
 var original="http://myoriginalurl"
 var addition=id
 console.log(id);
 var n =original.concat(addition)




//for testing
  window.alert(n)

  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML= n;


//for the real redirecting not active for now
//window.location=new
                          }




</script>


</html>
```

Currently in your code change the below, `new` to `newurl` - `new` is a reserved word.

```
function myFunction(id){
var original="http://myoriginalurl"
var addition=id
var newurl =original.concat(addition)
//for testing
window.alert(newurl)
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML= newurl;
//for the real redirecting not active for now
//window.location=new
}
```

I dont see a tag with `id=test1`, so you will get null exception in the console browser. Add a tag based on that and test.

I have added a snippet, please check.

Comment: I changed new to newurl but still no change.  alert not appearing and test paragraph not updating.

Comment: I have added a snippet, please check click on valA button you will get the alert

Comment: i have a paragraph with the id = test1 i just forgot to paste it in the question code. it seems like its not running myFunction at all. its breaking somewhere in calculatedUrl(). thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<form>

<div class="element1">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="id1" value="val1" class="hidden" ></label></div> 

<div class="element2">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="id2" value="val2" class="hidden" ></label></div> 

<div class="element3">" 
<input type="checkbox" name="name3" id="id3" value="val3" class="hidden" ></div>


<div class="element00"> 
<input type="button"onclick="myFunction(calculatedUrl());" name="button1" id="itemA" value="valA" ></label></div> 

</form>

<script>
function calculatedUrl(){
  var totalString=""
  var link1="some text"
  var link2="more  text"
  var link3="something else"

   if(document.getElementById("id1").checked == true){
     var totalString = totalString.concat(link1);

}

 if(document.getElementById("id2").checked == true){
         var totalString = totalString.concat(link2);


}

 if(document.getElementById("id3").checked == true){
         var totalString = totalString.concat(link3);

}
  return totalString

}

function myFunction(id){
 var original="http://myoriginalurl"
 var addition=id
 console.log(id);
 var n =original.concat(addition)




//for testing
  window.alert(n)

  document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML= n;


//for the real redirecting not active for now
//window.location=new
                          }




</script>


</html>
```